# Some Sieves problems

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I'm currently reading some lectures notes on Sieves Problems and I stumbled across a couple of problems I'm not able to solve. Honestly, since this is my first time I'm reading on analytic number theory, I'm not even sure how to attack them.

1. Given an odd positive integer $n$ we have: $$\#\{(p_1,p_2,p_3): \ p_i\text{'s are prime and } \  p_1+p_2+p_3=n \} \ll \frac{n^2}{\log(n)^3}$$ Now the bound intuitively makes sense, since we can choose the first two primes in about $\frac{n^2}{\log(n)^2}$ ways, but since it's clear that $n-p_1-p_2$ will not always be a prime, we need to multiply by $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ factor, but I'm not sure how to prove this.
2. A positive proportion of integers can be written as the sum of two prime
   numbers. I can prove this without using Sieves, but I'd like to see a proof employing them. I guess the proof would go something like that: Given $n$, the number of ways in which $n$ can be written as the sum is bounded, and then we can use this bound and the fact that $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log(n)}$ to prove the result.

Comment: Can you give an example of a problem similar to 1 that you have solved? 1 is a standard application of sieve tools (consider the set $n-p_1-p_2$ and sieve out small prime factors, for example), so it's unclear where the stumbling block is.

Comment: As for 2: let $r(n)$ be the numnber of ways of writing $n$ as the sum of two primes. It's definitely not true that $r(n)$ is bounded (it's not even bounded on average, as is easily verified). One way of showing that $r(n)>0$ for a positive proportion of $n$ is to use Cauchy–Schwarz to show that the number of such $n\le x$ is $\ge \bigl( \sum_{n\le x} r(n) \bigr)^2 \big/ \sum_{n\le x} r(n)^2$; the numerator (for which we need a lower bound) should be trivial, while the denominator (for which we need an upper bound) counts solutions to $p_1+p_2=p_3+p_4$.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm not able to give prior examples of Sieves problems I've solved because these are literally among the first ones I'm trying to solve. Also, you're right that $r(n)$ is not bounded in general, I should have clarified that I meant it is bounded by some function of $n$, something along the lines of log$_2(n)$, but since log$_2(n)\ll n^2/$log$(n)^3$, it doesn't really matter

Comment: As it turns out, $r(n)$ is going to have size $n/(\log n)^2$ when $n$ is even and large—look into Goldbach's conjecture. I strongly recommend starting with some of the very first sieve problems you find in the lecture notes and understanding their proofs (the upper bound $r(n) \ll n/(\log n)^2$, or the upper bound for the counting function of the twin primes, for example). There's no hope of moving on to more complicated problems without understanding how sieve tools (which are indeed daunting at first) can be applied to simpler ones.

Comment: @GregMartin I think you forgot the $\prod_{2<p|n}{p-1\over p-2}$ or $\prod_{p|n}\left(1+\frac1p\right) factor in the upper bound of $r(n)$.

Comment: When I said "size" instead of "asymptotic to", I meant to imply that I'm ignoring the leading constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is dedicated to OP's first question as the second one is basically hinted in Greg Martin's comment.

Let $r_k(n)$ be the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of exactly $k$ primes. Then we have
$$
r_k(n)=\sum_{p<n}r_{k-1}(n-p).
$$
Thus, to estimate $r_3(n)$ it suffices to estimate $r_2(n)$, the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of 2 primes. As this result is available in basically every sieve theory textbook, I am quoting it without a proof:

> **Theorem 1 (Schnirelman):** For large $n$, we have
> $$
> r_2(n)\ll{n\over\log^2n}\prod_{p|n}\left(1+\frac1p\right).
> $$

This indicates that
$$
r_3(n)
\ll{n\over\log^2n}\underbrace{\sum_{p_0<n}\prod_{p|n-p_0}\left(1+\frac1p\right)}_S
$$
Therefore, it suffices to show that $S\ll n/\log n$. Using the properties of Dirichlet convolution, we have
$$
S\le\sum_{p_0<n}\sum_{d|(n-p_0)}\frac1d=\sum_{d<n}\frac1d\color{red}{\sum_{\substack{p_0<n\\p_0\equiv n(d)}}1}
$$

Trivially the red sum is $\ll n/d$, so we can pick $D<n$ and obtain
$$
S\ll\underbrace{\sum_{d<D}\frac1d\color{red}{\sum_{\substack{p_0<n\\p_0\equiv n(d)}}1}}_{S_1}+\underbrace{\sum_{d\ge D}{n\over d^2}}_{\ll n/D}
$$

To estimate the remaining red sum, we quote Brun-Titchmarsh inequality:

> **Theorem 2 (Brun-Titchmarsh):** For all $x\ge q\ge1$ and $(a,q)=1$ we have
> $$
> \#\{p\le x:p\equiv a\pmod q\}\ll{x\over\varphi(q)\log x/q}.
> $$

Therefore, we see that
\begin{aligned}
S_1
&\ll\sum_{\substack{d<D\\(d,n)=1}}{1\over d\varphi(d)}{n\over\log n/d}+\sum_{\substack{d<D\\(d,n)>1}}\frac1d \\
&\ll{n\over\log n/D}\sum_{d\ge1}{1\over d\varphi(d)}+\log D
\end{aligned}

Finally, setting $D=\sqrt n$ gives $S\ll n/\log n$, completing the proof of
$$
r_3(n)\ll{n^2\over\log^3n}.
$$